# Combine two different types into one linq query and sort it

Tags: c#, linq

I have two database tables and I'm attempting to create a union query from them.  They have different structures:

```
public partial class Notes
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int VisitID { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
        public decimal AcctBalance {get; set; }
    }

public partial class SystemNotes
{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public int VisitID {get; set;}
   public int FacilityID {get; set;}
   public string Note {get; set;
   public DateTime NoteDate {get ;set; }
}
```

What I want to do is end up with a list of all the data in Notes format sorted by PostDate.  What I've tried so far is this:

```
List<Notes> requests = new List<Notes>();
            requests = _context.Notes.Where(i => i.VisitID == VisitID && i.isActive == true).ToList();
            List<SystemNotes> requests_s = new List<SystemNotes>();
            requests_s = _context.SystemNotes.Where(i => i.VisitID == VisitID).ToList();

            
            var unionA = from a in requests
                         select new 
                         {
                             a.ID,
                             a.VisitID,
                             a.Note,
                             a.PostDate,
                             a.AcctBalance
                         };
            var unionB = from b in requests_s
                         select new Notes()
                         {
                             ID = b.ID,
                             VisitID = (int)b.VisitID,
                             Note = b.Note,
                             PostDate = b.NoteDate,
                            
                             AcctBalance = (decimal)0.00
                         };
            List<Object> allS = (from x in unionA select (Object)x).ToList();
            allS.AddRange((from x in unionB select (Object)x).ToList());
```

However, PostDate is no longer recognized as an element inside the Object so I can't sort on it.  Also, it's in Object format not in Notes format which is what I want for where I'm sending my data.  I'm stuck on this one point.  Can you assist?  Or am I doing this the wrong way in general?

Comment: Use a join : var results = from n in _context.Notes
   join s in _context.SystemNotes on n.ID equals s.ID
   select new { notes = n, systemNotes = s };

Comment: var AB = (from A in unionA
                      select A).Union(unionB).ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you want:

```
    List<Notes> myNotes = new List<Notes> {
                    new Notes () {
                        ID = 1,
                        VisitID = 2
                    }
                };
                List<SystemNotes> mySystemNotes = new List<SystemNotes> {
                    new SystemNotes () {
                        ID = 3,
                        VisitID = 4
                    }
                };
    
                var result = myNotes.Select (mn => new { mn.ID, mn.VisitID })
                    .Union(mySystemNotes.Select (msn => new { msn.ID, msn.VisitID }))
.OrderByDescending(a=>a.ID);
    
                foreach (var currentItem in result)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine ("ID={0}; VisitID={1}", currentItem.ID, currentItem.VisitID);
                }
```

Comment: I get the following error 
Error CS1929 'IEnumerable<<anonymous type: int ID, int VisitID, string Note, DateTimeOffset? PostDateTZ, int? CollectorID, string DisplayName, decimal? ExpPayAmt, decimal? AcctBalance>>' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Union<<anonymous type: int ID, int? VisitID, string Note, DateTimeOffset? PostDateTZ, int CollectorID, string DisplayName, decimal ExpPayAmt, decimal AcctBalance>>... The problem is that there are different fields in each table